# how do i get multiple count queries with laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need some query builder to get result like this :

```
select 
A.`idalbum`, A.`title_en` as `title`, 
A.`desc_en` as `description`, A.`cover` as `cover`,
(SELECT COUNT(idgallery) AS gambar FROM gallery WHERE cate='1' AND albumid=A.idalbum) as gambar,
(SELECT COUNT(idgallery) AS videos FROM gallery WHERE cate='2' AND albumid=A.idalbum) as videos,
from `album` as A
```

what queries i should use?
in case, i can't use RAW because i need some paginate on laravel Eloquent

Comment: First you should try. if not success then paste your attempt here. Then ask for help.

Comment: ok thanks for your kindess

Comment: I agree @AnandGupta It's sad that people have stopped reading the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Comment: ok i got the answer. should i delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

i got this answer from another response :

```
$result = DB::table('album as A')
        ->select("A.idalbum", "A.title_en as title", 
        "A.desc_en as description", "A.cover as cover",
        DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(idgallery) AS gambar FROM gallery WHERE cate='1' AND albumid=A.idalbum) as gambar"), 
        DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(idgallery) AS videos FROM gallery WHERE cate='2' AND albumid=A.idalbum) as videos")
        )
        ->orderBy('A.date', 'asc')->paginate($this->perpage);


 return $result;
```

Should i delete this question?